# Make [cocoa-lumberjack] be a synonym for [lumberjack]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The [cocoa-lumberjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-lumberjack) tag has two questions, both of which are about the same open source Cocoa and Cocoa Touch logging framework, Lumberjack Logging, which is what the twenty-seven question tag [lumberjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lumberjack) is for.

The [cocoa-lumberjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-lumberjack) tag should be a synonym for [lumberjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lumberjack).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zey8567bcg

Answer (score 1):

Despite the obvious relevance of Hans' comment, the solution for this is in your hands.

Retag the two questions. Wait until 3:00 UTC and [cocoa-lumberjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-lumberjack) will [be no more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info).

Comment: I retagged the questions, and the edits were approved.